# как дописывать информацию в json файл на python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.x

у меня есть такой код:

```
import json
frame = [{'file':'filename',
              'frames':[
                  {'timestamp':number
                   ,'movement':type
                   }
                  ]
              }
             ]

json.dump(frame,open('test.json','w+'))
```

в общем,такое дело,допустим ,что у меня передаются в переменные number и type значения и их может быть 1000-3000 и мне нужно,чтобы каждый раз,когда приходят новые значения к этим переменным в мой json файл дописывались новые данные к старым,т.е ,чтобы это в самом json файле выглядело так:

```
  {'file':'filename',
                  'frames':[
                      {'timestamp':0.001,'movement':'type_1'},
                      {'timestamp':0.015,'movement':'type_2'},
                      {'timestamp':6.40,'movement':'type_3}
    # и так далее вплоть до 1000 элементов
                      ]
                  }
```

пне могу понять,как это реализовать

Comment: стоит явно упомянуть: в  **json** файле вы не можете увидеть что у вас вопросе показано (`{'':...}`). json формат использует двойные кавычки для строк. То что показано в вопросе это repr() словаря (что похоже на json, но НЕ является json).

Answer (score 2):

`1000-3000` это маленькое число на современных компьютерах. Используйте самое простое решение, которое работает. Загрузите файл целиком, измените и назад запишите:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('test.json')
data = json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))
data['frames'].append({'timestamp':0.015,'movement':'type_2'})
path.write_text(json.dumps(data), encoding='utf-8')
```

Для бóльших файлов можно http://jsonlines.org формат использовать — каждая строчка в файле содержит полный json документ. В этом случае, достаточно в самый конец записать данные:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json

frame = {'timestamp':0.015,'movement':'type_2'}
with open('frames.jsonlines', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(frame, file)
    file.write('\n')
```

Comment: ну у меня нет сразу готового,мне нужно сразу записывать значения,когда они приходят...в этом и проблема

Comment: @ЕгорАнтонович а чём у вас проблема? Вы не можете заменить константу на переменную: `data[‘frames’].append(frame)`?

Comment: да,но,разве индексы списка могут быть строчными?

Comment: Строчные индексы списка в коде в ответе не используются.  Если это не очевидно: `frame = {'timestamp':0.015,'movement':'type_2'}` в примере.

Answer (score 1):

В конце файла у тебя есть:

```
                  ]
              }
```

Допустим это последние 44 байта с конца. Можно без пробелов, просто оставить `]}` в конце и тогда рубить 2 байта вместо 44.

```
f = open('asd.json','a+') # открываем с курсором на конце
f.seek(f.truncate(f.tell()-2)) # обрезаем хвост и переходим в конец
f.write(',\n') # добавим запятую
f.write('{....}') # добавим кусок в массив
f.write(']}')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите добавлять записи в середину JSON структуры, просто дописывая в конец файла это не получится сделать, нужно писать в середину. Простейший способ конечно просто вычитывать текущий JSON файл, разобрать его, добавить в структуру нужный элемент, сериализовать в JSON и записать поверх старого файла, единственный недостаток что файл переписывать поверх будет не так быстро и кроме того будет в диске протирать дырку.

Второй способ это более низкоуровневый и сложный, нужно добавлять в Python структуру нужный элемент, сериализовать в JSON, сравнить с прошлым значением JSON из файла и пропустить общее начало и записать по смещению в файл где начинают данные отличаться, тогда нужно будет мало записывать данных и в основном будет меняться только конец, это позволит диску не изнашиваться так сильно.

Третий способ это хранить в файле не совсем корректный JSON, т.е. такой чтобы его концовка отсутсвовала, её можно считать фиксированной и добавлять при вычитывании файла. Тогда вам нужно будет в конец дописывать только данные типа `, {'timestamp':0.001,'movement':'type_1'}` и всё, а концовку потом явно добавлять когда нужно в коде, либо её добавить когда весь процесс собирания данных завершился. Концовка это будет несколько скобок и запятых закрывающих, их просто вручную добавить. Также можно нужный кусок данных сериализовать, найти смещение в файле куда точно его вставить и вставить в середину файла, современные оперционные системы позволяют вставлять кусок данных в середину файла.

Четвёртый способ это вместо одной JSON структуры иметь в файле их множество. Предлагаю каждую JSON структуру отдельно сериализовать в компактном виде без перевода строк (так вроде по умолчанию и делается), затем дописывать в конец файла строку с этой JSON структурой плюс в конце перевод строки. Ты можешь дописывать строки типа `{'timestamp':0.001,'movement':'type_1'}`, получится набор JSON структур по одной в каджой строке разделённых переводом строк. Потом в Питоне когда надо читаешь весь файл построчно и каждую строку де-сериализуешь как отдельный JSON и складываешь данные каждой структуры в одну общую. В итоге в таком виде можно ровно в конец файла добавлять, только это не будет один JSON объект а множество разделённых переводом строк.

Comment: хорошо,а если дозаписывать в json файл вот такими партиями только менять name и type {'file':'filename', 'frames':[ {'timestamp':0.001,'movement':'type_1'},]} ?можно ли так организовать?

Comment: JSON не позволяет в конец дописывать дополнительные данные, JSON просто не расчитан на поточное дополнение данными, если вы хотите просто в конец файла дописывать что-то тогда это возможно только если вы будете не корректный JSON поддерживать, допустим как я описал, без корректного завершения скобками. С другой стороны вы вполне можете просто сериализовать JSON в виде одной строки и дописывать в файл по строке, т.е. каждая строка это будет отдельный JSON полноценный, но тогда нужно будет потом также построчно вычитывать файл и каждую строку де-сериализовывать из JSON, типа потока JSON структур

Comment: у меня просто есть код,но там он дозаписывает через методы и классы при каждом запуске программы в конец файла,но код громоздкий и мне сказали,что это можно всё сократить и с помощью .dump всё записать

Comment: Этот код я уверен просто вычитывает файл с JSON полный, дополняет нужные элементы его структуры, сериализует полностью и обратно весь файл переписывает. Т.е. первый описанный мною способ. В конец он не может просто дописать т.к. это будет неправильный JSON. Конечно может код какой-то хакерский и они нужный элемент дописывают в середину файла, в современных операционных системах можно в середину дописывать, и ты можешь также сделать. Просто сериализуешь нужный кусок JSON, находишь в файле по какому смещению нужно его записать и вставляешь в середину.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul как писать в середину?

Comment: @eri Это же обычный файл. Современные ОС позволяют в середину файла вставлять данные. Главное найти нужное место. Если по предложенному мной принципу, т.е. когда каждая строка это JSON отдельный, тогда можно либо вначале пройтись по всему файлу отсчитав нужное число строк и вычислив нужную позицию. Либо второй вариант, это хранить отдельный файл с номерами смещений в байтах всех строк в файле, чтобы быстро по номеру строки можно было получить смещение в файле и туда писать, плюс обновлять индекс.

Comment: Писать поверх в любое место можно уже лет 50, но чтоб вставить... Сомневаюсь. Можно пример на любом языке?

Comment: @eri Мне казалось по памяти, что в WinAPI были функции вставки в середину файла, какие не помню. Просто некоторые файловые системы хранят файлы в виде отдельных кусков (chunks) сцепленных в список. Но в общем случае универсальное решение общее для всех ФС это просто перейти в нужную точку в середине файла, затем сместить всё содержимое на нужный размер (путём чтения и записи файла) и записать на освободившееся место нужный кусок. Думаю так всегда и делают когда хотят вставить в середину файла. Чтобы не зависить от типа ФС.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul тоесть предлагаешь сделать trunk и переместить кучу данных в конец? ручная дефрагментация файла... тут ещё куча проблем. не читая файл в память целиком искать куда вставить задачка тоже не простая

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую взять базу данных, хотяб sqlite и писать в неё все данные по мере поступления. когда эти данные понадобтся в формате json - тогда и собирать этот большой json.