# Удалить предпоследний элемент в записи json файл

Tags: python

После бекапа, скрипт добавляет к последнему json объекту запятую, что делает его повреждённым, я хочу удалить последнюю запятую что бы пофиксить это, но не особо получилось, подскажите что не так и как это можно обойти? Или может есть способ проще а я делаю из муха слона. Спасибо вот код ниже с моей попыткой:

```
    # Write all the documents to the file
    with open(filename, 'w+') as file:
        file.write('[')
        async for document in cursor:
            file.write(json.dumps(document, default=str))
            file.write(',')

        file.write(']')
        file.seek(0)
        text = file.read()
        if text != "[]":
            file.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
            file.truncate()
```

Comment: Каким образом в скрипте получается json (надеюсь, не конкатенацией строк)? Есть ли у вас возможность пофиксить его?

Comment: @СергейКох в каком смысле как получается? Он собирается буквально как показано в этом коде

Comment: Тогда используйте стандартные шаги - соберите `document` в список, преобразуйте в json, запишите в файл.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726673/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-json-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python

Answer (score 0):

Если все дело в цикле который всегда добавляет запятую в конце json

```py
async for document in cursor:
    file.write(json.dumps(document, default=str))
    file.write(',') # Проблемное место
```

То можно попробовать сделать вот так:

```py
async for i, document in enumerate(cursor):
    file.write(json.dumps(document, default=str))
    if i != len(cursor): # Добавляет запятую везде кроме последнего элемента
        file.write(',')
```

Но мне кажется лучше сделать вот так:

```py
documents = []
async for i, document in enumerate(cursor):
     documents.append(document)
json.dump(documents, file, default=str))
```

Comment: async for i, document in enumerate(cursor):
TypeError: 'AsyncIOMotorCursor' object is not iterable